# How to choose from a list in Razor?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I have a project in `C#` using the `MVC` design model.
The View receives a ViewModel from the Controller with a list of available cars and the user is supposed to be able to choose one from a drop-down list.

```
<div>
       <text>Choose car</text>
       <select name="Rental.CarID">
           @{ foreach (var n in Model.AvailableCars)
               {
                   <option value="n.id">@n.LicensePlate</option>
               }
           }
       </select>
   </div>
```

However the parameter `Rental.CarID` is being returned as null.

If I enter the `rental.CarID` manually like this, it does work:

```
<div>
       <text>Choose Car</text>
       <input type="number" name="Rental.CarID" />
</div>
```

How can I fix my code above so it returns the parameter?

Comment: What is `Rental.CarID`? Is it a variable on your razor page or is it supposed to be  coming from you Model? In either case, it is missing the prepended `@` notation.

Comment: @Daxton It is comng from a ViewModel. When I add `@` to it I get an error `The name Rental does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 1):

You need to let your razor page know you are trying to access a `Model` property. The notation is simply:

```
<select name="@Model.Rental.CarID">
      @{ foreach (var n in Model.AvailableCars)
          {
             <option value="@n.id">@n.LicensePlate</option>
          }
       }
</select>
```

Also, the code block containing the `foreach` is redundant. You can simply write:

```
@foreach (var n in Model.AvailableCars)
     {
         <option value="@n.id">@n.LicensePlate</option>
     }
```

Resulting in:

```
<select name="@Model.Rental.CarID">
      @foreach (var n in Model.AvailableCars)
      {
          <option value="@n.id">@n.LicensePlate</option>
      }
</select>
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error message `Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file.` Also, I don't see what you've done differently in the `foreach` code?

Comment: @Roger I would highly suggest taking a look at some simple Razor syntax tutorials. Here's a [start](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp). The difference with the `foreach` is small, you unnecessarily wrap a code block around your `foreach` with the `@ { }` notation. The message you're receiving makes it seem like you are assigning the `@model` multiple time in the page. Note that `@Model` and `@model` are **vastly** different as C# razor pages are **case sensitive**. I would read through some razor syntax tutorials to understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue that I see with your code is, option values are not associated with Ids. Could you check generated html code whether Options are associated with Ids or not.

To fix that issue please use this:

```
<option value="@n.id">@n.LicensePlate</option>
```

Comment: The HTML code that is generated has the same `name` ie`Rental.CarID` as it does when I ask for it to be entered manually

Comment: @Roger what about the `<option>` tags underneath select? Do they show expected ids (@n.id in your case) for `value` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<select name="@Model.Rental.CarID">
      @{ foreach (var n in Model.AvailableCars)
          {
             <option value=n.id>n.LicensePlate</option>
          }
       }
</select>
```

the first "@" before the foreach statement, should cover for the rest programmatic expressions.

Comment: When I add `@Model` I get this error message `Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file.` Also, adding `@` before the `foreach` and leaving it out later just shows`n.id` and `n.LicensePlate` when the code is generated, instead of the values

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `@Model.Rental.CarID` instead of Rental.ID.

And your code will be

```
<select name="@Model.Rental.CarID">
            @foreach (var n in Model.AvailableCars)
               {
                   <option value="@n.id">@n.LicensePlate</option>
               }

       </select>
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error message `Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file.`

Comment: Please share your model data.